# Dynamic pages in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have ember.js and json :

```
"id": 150,
"position": 2,
"talk_group_id": 5,
"type": "workshop",
```

with two types : workshops or presentation. 
I want display in one page only models with one types.

If it is possible I want to do this dynamic.. E.g. ember check types. Find 2 and create 2 dynamic pages in navigate and when you click first you seen list with type workshop.. I search this in google and I don't find similar problem..
If it no problem please give me some example.
Somebody help me with this?

Tnx for help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a computed property and filter all the model based on the type by doing something like:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  workshops: Ember.computed.filterBy('','type','workshop'),
  presentations: Ember.computed.filterBy('','type','presentation'),
});
```

Here is a working bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/keguq/2/edit